# jquery callback

Tags: jquery, callback

hi can someone explain to me the concept of jquery's callback
kinda stuck on this simple code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bar('',function(){
        foo();
    });         
});

function foo()
{
    alert('foo');
}

function bar()
{
    alert('bar');
}
```

so that `foo()` get executed first then `bar()`, but with the code above, only `foo()` gets executed and `bar` does not execute.

here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8zAA/2/)

Comment: `bar()` is the only one being executed in your sample.

Comment: @andre whiteaker - im implementing something in the jquery tuts http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Functions are first-class members in JavaScript and as such, can be assigned to variables and passed as arguments to other functions. The idea of a callback function is that one (or more) of parameters a function receives is a function reference which can be invoked under certain conditions. In your case, you're calling `bar` with two arguments but never doing anything with those parameters in `bar`. JavaScript doesn't call back functions automatically, you as the programmer must do that.

This is probably what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bar('',function(){ //this anonymous function maps to the parameter b in bar(a,b)
        foo(); //missing ; can lead to hard to track errors!
    });         
});


function foo()
{
    alert('foo');
}

//accept two parameters
// in this example code, given the call to bar() above, a will map to '' and b to the anonymous function that calls foo()
function bar(a, b) 
{
    alert('bar');
    if(typeof b === 'function'){ //check if b is a function
        b(); //invoke
    }
}
```

**Edit**

@Jared's suggestion definitely makes more sense - changed `if(b)` to `if(typeof b === 'function'){` before invoking `b`

Comment: lining them up sequentially would defeat the purpose for me to learn callbacks, is there a callback approach with my `foo()` and `bar()` functions?

Comment: Right, that was from before you changed your code, I'm editing my answer in reply to your edited question.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - How about `if (typeof b == 'function')`?

Comment: seems to be working, but kinda off, since i was thinking that callbacks would be placed in a queue where when the parent functions finishes the next in queue would be executed, as with the example in http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions, but i guess i might be wrong

Comment: @Jared Thank you for that - definitely a better check!

Comment: @ianace - That won't happen automatically, the developer needs to ensure that that's how it works. jQuery's `ready()` function for example, takes a callback function. If you dive into the [source for jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), you'll see that each time you attach a callback function to `ready`, it gets put into an array. When the ready event fires, each entry in that callback array is invoked one by one - the jQuery developers have had to write it that way, JavaScript only provides the mechanism for such a design pattern to be possible.

Comment: @ianace - For it to be interpreted, it must be called. See: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods